# Issue when adding a Facebook like button to my iOS app

Tags: ios, facebook, swift

I'm experimenting adding a Facebook like button to my app using swift. This is my code and also the steps I exactly took until now. I am wondering if I am missing doing any steps or if there is something wrong with the code?

1- Created a new Xcode project using Swift

2-added the following code to viewDiDLoad

3-imported "import Parse" and "import Social" as seen below

4-Created a bridging header file and imported FBSDKCoreKit/FBSDKCoreKit.h and FBSDKShareKit/FBSDKShareKit.h into it.

5-Added FBSDKCoreKit and FBSDKShareKit to my frameworks

And then I'm getting an "expected declaration" error on this line:
    likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/JCVDonline/?fref=ts"

Here is the full code:

```
    import UIKit
        import Parse
        import Social

        class NewsPageViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()

            var likeButton:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
            likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/JCVDonline/?fref=ts"
            likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
            likeButton.frame = CGRectMake(16,20, 290, 40)
            self.view.addSubview(likeButton)
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was I wanted to push a button and then have the like button show up. So I added an IBAction and it's working like gold!  next for me is to figure a way to change the button image :)
here is the working code by the way:

```
    import UIKit
    import Parse
    import Social

    class NewsPageViewController: UIViewController {
        override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        }
        @IBAction func likeOnFacebook(sender: AnyObject) {

            var likeButton:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
            likeButton.objectID = "https://www.facebook.com/JCVDonline/?fref=ts"
            likeButton.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
            likeButton.frame = CGRectMake(16,20, 290, 40)
            self.view.addSubview(likeButton)
         }
    }
```